# datatables plugin asynchronous load data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm fairly new to datatables and I was wondering if there is a way to load asynchronously 
the data into datatables plugin in such a manner that data is presented before the entire HTML table is created, like the following post describes:

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10021/asynchronous-itotalrecords-and-itotaldisplayrecords-update/p1

I actually need the table to be created as soon as there is enough data to render the table, and not wait to render all the table elements. My source for the datatables plugin is a pre-rendered HTML table. I found some samples on the net, but I couldn't make very much of them.

This is what I found:

https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

I couldn't find the mentioned "scripts/server_processing.php" file (throws an "file not found exception"). Is this actually a script I have to write myself ? If so, could anyoneo please share a sample, since I am a total newbie to PHP.

Any samples or relevat links appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For anyone else reading this question in the future, the `server_processing.php` file is something you would create.  It would be the file you use to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem, you can find a good MVC integration of datatables using an Ajax service to retrieve the data here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part